# Always getting pointer value, if the pointer object not exist or pointer is undefined?

Tags: php, parsing, parse-platform, parse-server

My question is related to **ParsePlatform PHP-SDK**:

I have a `post` table, in this table I have a pointer column `offer`. This pointer is optional for the post. This pointer may have an `objectId` of offer or may have a null or may have a wrong `objectId` of offer.

When I using this code:

```
$offer = $post->get('offer');
```

Returning a offer detail if exist, If not exist of have an invalid pointer value then it returning a blank value.

What I want is: I want to identify all the wrong pointer value, is this possible to know if the pointer value is wrong (Offer not exist)?

Here is my code:

```
try{
        $result = ParseCloud::run("searchForumPosts",$params);
        $posts_found = $result['completeLength'];
        foreach($result['posts'] as $post){
            $offer = $post->get('offer');
            $offer_name = "";
            if(!empty($offer)){
                $offer_name = $offer->getObjectId();
            }


        }

    }

     catch(ParseException $error){
        var_dump($error);
    }
```

1. I want `$offer_name=undefined` if `undefined` in post table.
2. I want `$offer_name=offer deleted`, if in post table `offer` column have an object id but the object is not exist in `offer` table.
3. I want `$offer_name = offerId` if the offer exist in offer table. This is working. I am not able to track first two conditions

Here is my Parse Cloud Function:

```
// give suggestions for the offer number on min of 2 numbers
Parse.Cloud.define("searchForumPosts", function(request, response) {
    isRequestLegitimate(request).then(function(result) {
        if (result.legitimateRequest) {
            var query = new Parse.Query("ForumPost");
            var completeLength = 0;
            findTextInSearchTerms(query, request.params.wildcard, "searchTerms").then(function(ids) {
                var query2 = new Parse.Query("ForumPost");
                if ((ids == -1 || ids.length == 0)) {
                    completeLength = 0;
                    return [];
                } else {
                    completeLength = ids.length;
                    // not very efficient, if the wildcard is empty we still ask for findTextInSearchTerms, change that later on
                    query2.containedIn("objectId", ids);

                    if (request.params.pageSize && request.params.pageNumber) {
                        var pageSize = parseInt(request.params.pageSize);
                        var pageNumber = parseInt(request.params.pageNumber);

                        query2.limit(pageSize);
                        if (pageNumber > 1) {
                            query2.skip((pageNumber - 1) * pageSize);
                        }
                    }
                    query2.include("offer");
                    query2.include("offer.artist");
                    query2.include("creator");
                    query2.descending("createdAt");
                    query2.select("objectId","offer.isActive","offer.stopDate", "offer", "offer.objectId", "offer.artist", "offer.artist.firstname", "offer.artist.lastname", "offer.title", "offer.picHash", "title", "text", "offer.offer", "creator", "creator.firstname", "creator.lastname", "replies");
                    return query2.find({
                        useMasterKey: true
                    });
                }
            }, function(error) {
                return error;
            }).then(function(foundPosts) {
                console.log('foundPosts',foundPosts);
                if (foundPosts.length > 1) {
                    var sortBy = request.params.sortBy;
                    if (sortBy == "artist") {
                        foundPosts.sort(function(a, b) {
                         console.log('foundPosts a',a);
                         console.log('foundPosts b',b);


                            var nameA = 'ZZZZZZZZZ';
                            var nameB = 'ZZZZZZZZZ';
                            if (a.offer) {
                                nameA = ((a.offer || {}).artist || {}).lastname.toUpperCase();
                            }
                            if (b.offer) {
                                nameB = ((b.offer || {}).artist || {}).lastname.toUpperCase();
                            }

                            if (nameA < nameB) {
                                return -1;
                            }
                            if (nameA > nameB) {
                                return 1;
                            }
                            // names must be equal
                            return 0;
                        });
                    } else if (sortBy == "author") {
                        foundPosts.sort(function(a, b) {
                            var nameA = 'ZZZZZZZZZ';
                            var nameB = 'ZZZZZZZZZ';
                            if (a.offer) {
                                nameA = ((a.offer || {}).creator || {}).lastname.toUpperCase();
                            }
                            if (b.offer) {
                                nameB = ((b.offer || {}).creator || {}).lastname.toUpperCase();
                            }

                            if (nameA < nameB) {
                                return -1;
                            }
                            if (nameA > nameB) {
                                return 1;
                            }
                            // names must be equal
                            return 0;
                        });
                    }
                }
                console.log('foundPostsfoundPosts',foundPosts);

                var results = {};
                results.completeLength = completeLength;
                results.posts = foundPosts;
                response.success(results);
            }, function(error) {
                response.error(error);
            });
        } else {
            response.error("You must be logged in!");
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "pointer column"? Afaik that's not a sql concept. Are you already using foreign keys, or is that what you're looking for?

Comment: Also, since `$offer = $post->get('offer');` is php & not sql, you're presumably using some abstraction layer in between. What kind of layer? What does the Post class look like?

Comment: @Stratadox The question never says anything about SQL, the tags relate to ParsePlatform and ParseServer.

Comment: Ha, my bad, must've misread.

Comment: Just to understand what you need. Do you want to perform a query that will return all posts with invalid object ids in the offer field?

Comment: Yes my query is regarding the parse server. Sorry I forgot to mention in Question detail. I am adding now.

Comment: @DaviMacêdo Let me explain. I have an Cloud function which returns all posts based on search criteria. In loop I'm am getting other fields of post and more details about the pointers. Adding code to question. Please check

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are doing `query2.include("offer");` in your cloud code query, the Parse Server will try to automatically fetch the associated offer for each of the posts. Therefore it will only return `offer.objectId` if it exists and it is valid. It means that you will receive either a valid `offer.objectId` or undefined in your client code. You will not be able to distinguish the case in which it was deleted or was undefined. If distinguishing it really matters to you, you should not use the `query2.include("offer");` in your cloud code query, but fetch each of the offers separately so you can send this information to the client code.

Comment: It always returning a `Offer Deleted` for all offfer that exists. And `blank` value for deleted offer and undefined offer

Comment: Can you share the code of your cloud code function?

Comment: I just updated my Question with Cloud Function code

Comment: I can't see it. I think you tried to update my answer instead of your question.